# Change circuit while sketch is running on arduino

Tags: arduino

I've tried to find an answer to my worries but without "definitive" answers.

I'm a noob in electronic so excuse me if it sounds obvious.

My question is: is it safe to update a circuit while a sketch is running? If I'm creating a new circuit and a previous sketch is still on the chip?

I found that normally by disconnecting the ground it should be ok, can you confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As another general rule: First program your microcontroller, *then* connect the circuit.

Imagine this situation:

- Your previous sketch had all outputs actively driven high by default;
- Your new circuit connects various inputs to ground by default;

The current drawn due to this situation may easily exceed the absolute maximum ratings of your microcontroller and (by far most) Arduino's have no protection at all.

One precaution I usually take when experimenting, is to connect series resistors to all Arduino pins unless absolutely sure that a series resistor will corrupt the signal. Anything between 5V/20mA=250Ω and 4kΩ7 will be a good start to protect *most* circuits from bad wiring.

Answer (score 2):

If the power isn't connected, it doesn't really matter what you do to the circuit (within reason, you can still mess things up with static shocks etc. but let's ignore that for now). Also, the sketch isn't actually running if the power to the arduino CPU isn't connected. The CPU is just sitting there waiting for power, same thing as the circuit.

However, I generally disconnect the Vcc line rather than ground in order to break the circuit power. In any case, it sounds like you are not doing anything potentially harmful to either you or the electronics.

Comment: Can I just unplug the arduino usb cable ?

Answer (score 0):

As general rule: never work in a circuit if it's powered on.
A lot of exception can apply, if you know exactly what are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this and take precaution by uploading the '[Bare Minimum](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BareMinimum)' example sketch before changing the circuit to an incompatible one.

You might also want to clear (portions of) the [EEPROM](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM) if that's necessary.